# Запятая в предложении с «относительно»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Следует ли ставить запятую после «темы»?

*Относительно научного освещения данной темы(,) приходится констатировать, что работ, в которых применяются именно исторические методы исследования, остается очень мало.*

Answer (score 1):

[относительно](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE), *нареч. и предлог*
**2.** *предлог с род. п.* По отношению к кому-либо, чему-либо, в отношении кого-либо, чего-либо. *Относительно ее я не имел никаких определенных намерений и ни о чем не мечтал* (А. П. Чехов. Страх).

В Вашем предложении слово **относительно** является **предлогом** — запятая в указанном месте не требуется. Предлог обычно используется в научной и официальной речи.

***Относительно научного освещения данной темы приходится констатировать, что...***

Вот похожие предложения.

*Относительно первого тома приходится констатировать (а относительно второго предвидеть) факт несколько иной группировки материала, нежели в вышеизложенном плане...* (Е. Поливанов. Введение в языкознание для востоковедов)

*В докладе МИД относительно договора по этому вопросу говорилось, что в результате советско-американских переговоров было достигнуто...*

*Своим мнением относительно данной темы с СБЭ поделился заслуженный тренер Эстонии Геннадий Толмачёв...*

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, предложение **стилистически некорректно.**

Вызывает сомнение сочетание ***констатировать относительно (научного) освещения.***  Если это управление неверно, то оборот **нужно обособлять** в обязательном порядке.

Но и в случае обособления он смотрится неестественно, скорее эту фразу нужно записать так: ***Если говорить относительно научного освещения данной темы, то  приходится констатировать, что...***

Но и это предложение выглядит не лучшим образом (много слов при малом количестве информации). Конечно, это научный стиль, но неужели нельзя писать короче и понятнее.

Вариант редактирования

***Что касается научного освещения данной темы, то работ, где применяются именно исторические методы исследования, пока еще очень мало.***